# Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pip

i know there is some poste like that but i try so mutch solutions and they don't work... 
So i wanna build https://github.com/daid/Cura on MAC OS X, but it's don't works, my problem is:

When i try to did that on my virtualenv:

```
$ pip install -r requirements_darwin.txt
```

At the end he give me an error :

```
$ Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/...
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you give us the entire output of the install? There may be errors there that would be helpful in trouble shooting this.

Comment: ...Not to mention that as a rule, that error message explicitly refers to a log file.